# basic understanding of simple socket server

Tags: python, sockets, networking, tcp

I am new to socket programming and am trying to understand how sockets work. Presently I am trying to play with python socket library to see how it works.

Now there are a few things that I am not able to wrap my head around. 
Let's take an example as shown [here](http://www.bogotobogo.com/python/python_network_programming_server_client.php) of a simple echo client and server written in python using the Python socket library.

The **echo server** looks like the below
    # echo_server.py
    import socket

```
host = ''        # Symbolic name meaning all available interfaces
port = 12345     # Arbitrary non-privileged port
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((host, port))
s.listen(1)
conn, addr = s.accept()
print('Connected by', addr)
while True:
    data = conn.recv(1024)
    if not data: break
    conn.sendall(data)
conn.close()
```

The **echo client** looks like the below

```
# echo_client.py
import socket

host = socket.gethostname()    
port = 12345                   # The same port as used by the server
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((host, port))
s.sendall(b'Hello, world')
data = s.recv(1024)
s.close()
print('Received', repr(data))
```

**My Questions**

1. In echo_server.py when I say conn, addr = s.accept(), accept() does two things. 1. it returns the connecting client's address (ip and port), which is stored in addr and 2. It creates a new socket (called client socket) that can be referenced here using conn and is used to interact with the connected client.

   > Now what happens when another client also connects to this server? Does the conn and addr variables get overwritten with the new values? Or how is it handled?
2. Again in echo_server.py, the s.listen(1) suggests there is a maximum of 1 backlog allowed, which I seem to understand only theoretically that it is the maximum number of clients that the server wants to allow to keep waiting in the queue while the server is busy dealing with the already connected client.

   > Is there some simple practical example to demo this ?

Answer (score 0):

> Now what happens when another client also connects to this server? Does the conn and addr variables get overwritten with the new values? Or how is it handled?

In your example, nothing interesting will happen. The attempt to connect will hang. Each client call to `connect()` must match a server call to `accept()`. Since you call `accept()` exactly once, at most one client will ever connect.

If you want to be able to accept connections from subsequent clients, serially, try this:

```
import socket

host = ''        # Symbolic name meaning all available interfaces
port = 12345     # Arbitrary non-privileged port
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((host, port))
s.listen(1)
while True:
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    print('Connected by', addr)
    while True:
        data = conn.recv(1024)
        if not data: break
        conn.sendall(data)
    conn.close()
```

If you want to be able to accept connections from clients in parallel, ie. from multiple clients simultaneously, then you have more work to do. But that isn't really part of your question today.

Comment: Yea, in understand how placing s.accept() inside while makes the server accept multiple connections, may be not in parallel but subsequently in a serial manner, which again makes sense. But then, what good is that? I mean is it not the same as placing s.accept() outside and have one client alone connect with it. Is it that while being inside the while, that's when the concept of backlog comes into the picture? If yes, is there a way an example demonstrating it will be really appreciated. 
Also, what about the conn and add variables for every accept() ? Does it get overwritten by every client?

Comment: Remember, s.accept() is a blocking call to the listening socket "s".  When a client "connects" to the listening socket, a new socket is created which is passed back to the variable/reference "conn".   The references "conn" and "addr" will get new values with each additional call to s.accept(), as with any python function call of that form.  I would assume that the backlog allows for the number of incoming connection requests pending an accept before rejecting incoming requests.

Answer (score 0):

> > Now what happens when another client also connects to this server? Does the conn and addr variables get overwritten with the new values? Or how is it handled?

As pointed out by Rob in another answer, your code will accept only one client. The `accept` have to be called for any connect request from client. And code accordingly. Now coming to your question, yes, the (conn,addr) pair will be overwritten. The code should take care of passing them on to some connection thread before calling `accept` again for new connection.

> > Is there some simple practical example to demo this ?s there some simple practical example to demo this ?

In the updated code for accepting multiple clients try not calling `accept` after few connections and notice the TCP connection status table (with `netstat` for example) to see the behavior for varying values of backlog.